# How can I use Lilypond to produce transposed notation?

Tags: lilypond, transposition

Lilypond has a [`\transpose`](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/changing-multiple-pitches#transpose) command: the following notation

```
\transpose c d { \relative c' { c4 d e f g } }
```

produces

[image]

I was wondering if I can use this command somehow to produce transposed *notation*, i.e.

```
\relative d' { d4 e fis g a }
```

or if there are another other tricks to do this. Currently I'm using find & replace in a text editor, which is rather error-prone.

I am using Lilypond's notation to store melodies for another program, that's why I want to have it in a specific key rather than to rely on `\transpose` to be present.

Comment: a job for grep?

Comment: I'm certain I can program a solution in half a dozen languages - I was just hoping Lilypond has this built-in...

Comment: `\lilygrep`? :-)

Comment: SInce there are some doubts in existing answers: You want to create lilypond code containing the transposition result, not simply a transposed score - corrrect?

Comment: @guidot correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused about what LilyPond does.  LilyPond is not an editor.  It processes your input but does not work on it.  While there are things like `\displayLilyMusic`, they are not really reflecting a relation to the input of the program.

Instead you need (or at least you call for) an editor that has a grasp of LilyPond input syntax and can work with it.  There does not appear to exist a useful Emacs mode for this, but the LilyPond IDE ["Frescobaldi"](https://www.frescobaldi.org/) has numerous input conversion tools for converting absolute/relative notation and also for transposing the input in-place.

Comment: There is also the command line utility [python-ly](https://github.com/frescobaldi/python-ly), but the Frescobaldi IDE is much more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

How is your example not transposed notation?  Are you thinking of, say, `\transpose d c`, namely transposing what is entered as `d` to notation based on `c`?  If you are producing MIDI, you may also want to look up the `\transposition` command.  Actually, what is wrong with the [LilyPond manual section for transposing instruments?](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/displaying-pitches#instrument-transpositions)

Comment: I am using Lilypond's notation to store melodies for another program, that's why I want to have it in a specific key rather than to rely on `\transpose` to be present.